# Preserve multiple hyperlinks per shape in PDF

Tags: pdf, microsoft-visio, hyperlink

I have several Visio diagrams describing our processes (in Visio Professional 2010).  Some of the diagrams reference other processes.  In Visio, I'm able to add multiple hyperlinks to a shape.  I needed to save our Visio diagrams as PDF for others in the company to view.  For the most part, this worked great.  In the cases where a shape had multiple hyperlinks, though, only the first hyperlink was preserved.  Is there a way to preserve all hyperlinks associated with a shape when saving as a PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. You could try to add a mouseover effect in the PDF, as described here:

http://www.traum-projekt.com/fileadmin/user_upload/sonstige/pdf/2/Tutorial_popup.pdf

I don't have acrobat to try it, but maybe you could add some hyperlinks to this optionally displayed layer(s)